# I can't add a custom dictionary in Microsoft Word 2019

Tags: microsoft-word

I would like to add a custom dictionary, to can add word to it.

I go to options-->proofing and click the button Custom dictionaries.

But all the options are grey, I can't create a new one neither browse to find the default custom dictionary.

I have tried in another Word and I have enabled the buttons to can add or browse to find an existing dictionary.

Which could be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: In *Control Panel > Programs and Features* right-click Office and select Change to repair. If this doesn't help, reinstall Office.

Comment: @harrymc I have tried to reinstall and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you see any dictionaries in Custom dictionaries?

Comment: @harrymc I have realized that if I use another user in the same computer, it works. So I guess it is a problem with the user. But I would try to avoid to delete the user and create a new one.